# Проблема смены порта ssh в связке solusKVM + Centos 6, VPS

Tags: linux, centos, ssh, centos6

Хочу сменить стандартный *22й* ssh порт на порт 20545

правлю файл

> /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Ищу там

> Port 22

и меняю его на

> Port 20545

потом перезагрузка

> /etc/init.d/sshd restart

потом захожу в настройки фаервола

> vim /etc/sysconfig/iptables

и заменяю строку

> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT

на

> -A INPUT -p tcp -m tcp --dport 20545 -j ACCEPT

Сохраняю

> service iptables save

И перезагрузка

> service iptables restart

Но при таких комбинациях я не могу зайти в свой ssh через порт 20545. Где я допустил ошибку? В чем еще может быть проблема?

Comment: А на локалхосте порт открыт?

Comment: Если вы имеете в виду работу сайта, то все вроде ок работает. Какой командой это можно проверить?

Comment: Стоит еще панель Vesta, может там надо менять iptables в первую очередь?

Comment: `nmap -p 20545 localhost`

Comment: Я заметил что правила iptables после сохранения и ребута по SSH меняються на старые, те что прописаны в панеле Vesta, так что все правила желательно через нее писать. Сделал nmap: PORT: 20545/tcp STATE: open SERVICE: unknown Nmap done: 1 IP address (1 host up) scanned in 0.09 seconds. Но при этом соединение по этому порту не работает, только 22 и все.

Comment: Может у провайдера какие-то ограничения стоят? Потому что ssh слушает с локалхоста этот порт.